# JS Loop is looping and crashing browser?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, memory, crash

```
for (i=0;i<channelName.length;i++) {
        if (channelName[i]=="channel"||channelName[i]=="user") {
        checkUserDuplicate(channelName[i]);
    }
}
```

This loop is causing an "out of memory" crash in all browsers. can anyone see why? It seems to be crashing at the IF statement and then causing an infinite loop somehow.

If you're wondering what the code does, it finds the keywords "channel" and "user" in an array of undefined length, then gets the string at the next position.

Any help would be much appreciated as I have been sitting here puzzled for 2 hours.

EDIT: channelName is a URL like http://www.youtube.com/user/username

this is the function:

```
function checkUserDuplicate(channelName) {
var idarray=[];match=0;$('.channels').each(function(){idarray.push(this.id)});
for (i=0;i<idarray.length;i++) {
    var current=channelName.toLowerCase();compare=idarray[i].toLowerCase();
    if (current==compare) {callError(channelName+" already exists in this collection");match=1;}
} if (match==0) {checkExists(channelName);}
```

}

It's a mess :)

Comment: What's the code for `checkUserDuplicate`? I guess `i` is a global variable, and you're chancing its value in that function? Exactly, please declare your variables.

Comment: Not with what is currently shown. What is the value and how large is `channelName`? What does `checkUserDuplicate` do (*I'm assuming that's looping as well and possibly causing an infinite loop*)?

Comment: @Teemu Sorry for that, no it's not a global variable. The code is extremely long.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I will double check this now

Comment: Then they probably share the same scope. Please add an example with which we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I've sorted it now. There was something wrong with checkUserDuplicate. Because idarray.length was = 0 when there was nothing in the array it was causing an infinite loop somehow.

I just added an `if (idarray.length==0)` to bypass this

Answer (score 1):

In your `for` loop, if you don't specify `var i = 0;`, it's globally accessible then. And in your other functions, you may modify the value of i and cause it doesn't increment as expected ends up with an infinite loop.

Sorry I didn't read the code since it's pretty messy, but that could be the reason

Comment: Yeah haha sorry about the messy code. I just always write condensed like this, no reason but as long as I know what it means :D

Comment: @LewisHarris so.. is that the reason?

Comment: No. The problem was with idArray.length was==0, so caused an infinite loop. I wasn't aware that idArray getting the array date after this section of code executes.

Answer (score 0):

In the checkUserDuplicate function it counts the amount of DIVs within a scope of classes. If there is no classes or DIVs the count is 0, and passed on to the for loop and creates a recursive loop.